# mongodb aggregation if condition - if true then execute filter

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a query that get arrays of  profession and subProfession, and return all Therapist that has a matching profession/subProfession

But if both arrays of profession and subProfession are empty, then return all therapists.

here is a pseudo code of the logic I'm trying to get:

```
        professionsFlag = professions.length != 0;
        subProfessionsFlag = subProfessions.length != 0;
        Therapist.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $cond: {if: professionsFlag || subProfessionsFlag, 
                        then:
                        {$or: [
                            { profession: { $in: professions } },
                            {
                                subProfession: {
                                    $elemMatch: { $in: subProfessions }
                                }
                            }
                        ]}
                    },
                }
            },
```

this code fails with `unknown top level operator: $cond`

what is the correct why to do so?

NOTE: The `$or` part of the query works as expected.

Comment: The `$match` condition should be made dynamically with the simple javascript code not inside the aggregation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this code:

```
      let filter = {
            $match: {
                image: { $exists: true, $ne: null },
                'clinic.city': params.place.value
            }
        };

        if ( professions.length != 0 || subProfessions.length != 0) {
            filter.$match.$or =  [
                { profession: { $in: professions } },
                {
                    subProfession: {
                        $elemMatch: { $in: subProfessions }
                    }
                }
            ];
        }

        Therapist.aggregate([
            filter,
        ], callback);
```

Comment: If this solution solves your problem you should mark the answer to let others know this thread is closed. Good job on solving you own question by the way :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the `correct` way of doing stuff in mongo